# Calculate metrics for db call(for DAO Class) from java using Netfix Hystrix

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, metrics, hystrix

I would like calculate metrics for a db call from DAO class using hystrix(new to this topic). Can someone point me to some tutorial for understanding of calculating metrics using hystrix.

Comment: What kind of metrics? And Hystrix is probably not the right tool to do that with.

Comment: Would like to see the latency for the data fetching from db when the application deployed to cloud environment.